# Want to create custom error page for Grizzly server

Tags: grizzly

We want custom error pages has to be served whenever there is an error, because default error page provides too much information which we don't want. Please provide document for the same, if any.

Grizzly server version: 2.3.16

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().setDefaultErrorPageGenerator(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to get the `ErrorPageGenerator` working, you need to attach it to the server configuration **before Grizzly server is started**.

So you should be doing something like that:

```
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
    baseUri,
    resourceConfig,
    false // so Grizzly won't start automatically
);

httpServer.getServerConfiguration().setDefaultErrorPageGenerator(...);

httpServer.start();
```